# Converting polylines as paths to polygons in one shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon-creation, polyline-creation

I have acquired raw path GPS data where seabird colony boundaries were physically recorded and uploaded in the form of polylines.

A lot of these polylines are a bit messy and overlapping, but there are about 10 non-contiguous colonies on the map area.

I wish to convert these into polygons under one shapefile to represent seabird colonies. I have attempted several different methods, but in converting polylines to polygons under one feature class file, I have a hard time with most of the polylines converting as if they are not perfectly connected the command will not recognize the polygon I wish to create.

Is there any easier way of smoothing and connecting polylines other than manually using the create features tool?

[image: portion of the map of polygons I have converted and the polylines needing to be converted into polygons]

[image: magnified area of polylines which need to be edited]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing your data? Do you have basic, standard or advanced arcmap license?

Comment: @BERA I have added two photos in the description, and I have a standard ArcMap license. Thanks